# Finding a map list index by specifying a map value

Tags: dart

I have a List that contains Maps.
I would like to know what the list index of a specific Map is by providing a Map value.
In my case, the unique value is for the key "Item ID".

In the example below, how would I find the list index of the map where key 'itemID' == '222'?

```dart
List<Map<String, dynamic>> itemList = [
    {
      'itemID': '111',
      'itemDescription': 'Lolipop',
    },
    {
      'itemID': '222',
      'itemDescription': 'Haribo',
    },
    {
      'itemID': '333',
      'itemDescription': 'KitKat',
    },
  ];
```

Updated to add code example. Sorry, really new to this and Dart.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the list index of a map item in the list? I want to provide a map value for a key and in return, I want to know that the list index is of that map.

Comment: Please provide what you have tried.

Comment: Also please provide examples of what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you saying that you want to return the first `Map` that contains the given key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```dart
int indexWhereValue<K, V>(List<Map<K, V>> maps, K key, V value) => 
   maps.indexWhere((map) => map[key] == value);
```

Comment: Thank you, Irn. How would it work for a list like this?

List<Map<String, dynamic>> itemList = [
  {
    'itemID': '111',
    'itemDescription': 'Lolipop',
  },
  {
    'itemID': '222',
    'itemDescription': 'Haribo',
  },
  {
    'itemID': '333',
    'itemDescription': 'KitKat',
  },
];

Comment: Sorry, really new to this. Not sure how to show it clearly.

Comment: Ahh, got it. Thanks a lot, Irn. Ehhh, my reputation is too low to upvote your answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will only give you the *first* result that matches. If you want all maps that have a certain key,value pair, you'll need to iteratively move forward your starting location after each find.